# ラジオボタンを押すとすべての選択肢が変わってしまう。

Tags: html, angularjs

AngularJSを使って以下のようにラジオボタンを動的に配置したのですが、1つのラジオボタンを押すとすべてのラジオボタンが選択状態になってしまい困っています。どこが間違っているのか教えて下さい。よろしくおねがいします。

```js
271   $scope.satisfactions=[];
272   for(var i=1; i<6; i++){
273     $scope.satisfactions.push(i);
274   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
28   <div class="form-group">
 29     <label for="satisfaction" class="control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12" class="fontrol-label">満足度</label>
 30     <div ng-repeat="satisfaction in satisfactions" class="checkbox-inline">
 31     <label for="satisfaction{{satisfaction}}">
 32       <input type="radio" id="satisfaction_{{satisfaction}}" name="satisfaction_{{satisfaction}}" ng-model="$parent.inquery.satisfaction" value="$index"/> {{satisfaction}}
 33     </label>
 34     </div>
 35   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$index`は0から始まるので値がズレませんか？

AngularJSでラジオボタンを使うときは、ng-modelに同じ値を指定してvalueもしくはng-valueで値を設定すると良いと思います。

```
$scope.satisfactions=[];
for(var i=1; i<6; i++){
  $scope.satisfactions.push(i);
}
$scope.select_satisfaction=1;
```

・・・

```
<label><input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.select_satisfaction" ng-value="satisfaction"> {{satisfaction}}</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

ラジオボタンの`value`が同じ値になっているのが原因ではないかと思います。
`value`にindexを設定するのであれば、こんな感じに変更してみてください。

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="satisfaction" class="control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12" class="fontrol-label">満足度</label>
  <div ng-repeat="(index, satisfaction) in satisfactions" class="checkbox-inline">
    <label for="satisfaction{{satisfaction}}">
     <input type="radio" id="satisfaction_{{satisfaction}}" name="satisfaction_{{satisfaction}}" ng-model="$parent.inquery.satisfaction" value="{{index}}"/> {{satisfaction}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```